# Проблемы кроссплатформерного программирования

Tags: кроссплатформенность

Какие могут быть проблемы у кроссплатформерного программирования? Желательно подробно пояснить суть проблемы и кратко её решение.

*Нужна проблема для исследовательской работы по теме "Кроссплатформерное программирование", тоесть проблема любого типа, лучше та, которая хорошо обьясняется*

Comment: Поподробнее... Кроссплатформенность понятие растяжимое - можно кроссплатформенно писать под С/С++ (переопределяя типы через #define), а можно на C#/Java поверх виртуальной машины. В общем нужны детали

Comment: Нужна проблема для исследовательской работы по теме "Кроссплатформерное программирование", тоесть проблема любого типа, лучше та, которая хорошо обьясняется

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код ядра Linux, папку arch. Там все кищит кроссплатформенностью.

Comment: А там есть проблемы? Мне банально нужна проблема и её решение)

Comment: Вам нужно окончательное решение проблем кроссплатформенности? Однако...

Comment: Проблема в том что эта папка по количеству кода в 20 раз больше самого "кроссплатформенного" кода ядра.

Comment: И сразу забыть. Тот еще ад, если не пользоваться чем-то готовым. А то написал я как-то класс объединяющий WinAPI и XWindow. Хорошее вышло развлечение.

Comment: Смотрите работы Osterhaut'а.

Comment: Ну так вот и проблема. Можно написать что-то. С точки зрения практической, Qt или Swing более-менее справляются.

Comment: Автора пришел в восторг от Sleep(). 

А кто-то тут ему вообще посмотреть на ядро предлагал.

Comment: >А там есть проблемы? Мне банально нужна проблема и её решение)

 Так создай её себе сам :)

Comment: Не могу добавить комментарий в свою ветку. Именно такой реализации sleep() в которой указывается задержка в миллисекундах я не нашел в линуксе. Если эта проблема не подходит могу предложить другую: критические секции. В винде и линуксе используются совершенно разные функции для работы с ними. Инициализация критической секции в винде: InitializeCriticalSection(), в линуксе - pthread_mutex_init(). Можно написать класс, который в зависимости от операционной системы будет вызывать те или иные функции.

Как вариант можно заглянуть в работу с потоками.

Comment: Реализация Sleep в миллисекундах для линукса тривиальна

    #define Sleep(t) usleep((t)*1000)

и вряд ли может быть зачтена как результат  исследовательской работы, которую надо сделать автору.

А вот идея реализации критических секций Windows мьютексами потоков в Linux выглядит привлекательной и не очень сложной в реализации (конечно надо учесть тонкости планировщика и аккуратно менять атрибуты потоков).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Кроссплатформенное программирование подразумевает программирование и не стоит вмешивать сюда виртуальные машины.

Как вариант проблемы: сделать программу на c++ кроссплатформенной. Есть некая программа под windows, которую нужно портировать на линукс. Для простоты: программа консольная. Задача в принципе проста, откомпилировать в новой операционной системе, но когда пробуешь это сделать, понимаешь, что не все так просто. Не находятся заголовочные .h файлы, нет некоторых классов, а так же отсутствует часть функций. Дальше остается упорно искать решения по каждой проблеме: найти аналоги .h файлов с описанием нужных функций и написать кроссплатформенные функции, которые в зависимости от ОС будут вызывать нужные системные функции.

Пример: функциия `Sleep(int t)` в винде делает паузу в t миллисекунд. В линуксе есть только `usleep(int t)` в который передается время в микросекундах. Для линукса была написана новая функция: `void Sleep(unsigned int i){ usleep(i*1000); }`

Задача кроссплатформенности сделать так, чтобы работало одинаково на нескольких ОС.

Comment: Идеальное решение, спасибо Вам огромное. Считайте что не я защитил работу, а Вы :)

Comment: Не только разных ОС, но и разных процессорных архитектурах

Comment: >В линуксе есть только usleep(int t) в который передается время в микросекундах.

Что за бред? Есть sleep, которая секунды получает.

Comment: @mikillskegg, как ждал. Секунда это очень-очень долго. А иногда требуется всего лишь остановить программу, чтобы она не грузила напрасно процессор.

Comment: Тогда не пишите "только".

Comment: @mikels, к данной теме не относится, но дурное занятие так (usleep-ом) беречь CPU. 

На самом деле Вы должны ждать некого события. Ну, если уж не можете для себя сфорулировать, чего Вы ждете, то воспользуйтесь  sched_yield() или  pthread_yield() для передачи управления диспетчеру и перемещении себя в конец очереди runable.

Comment: @mikillskegg, под только я имел в виду, что не нашел аналога, кроме как usleep().

@avp, не сказал бы. Порой требуется выполнять некие действия в бесконечном цикле. И намного проще использовать Sleep(), чем пользоваться диспетчерами, тем более я с ними раньше не работал и не особо то понимаю зачем они здесь. Только сегодня использовал Sleep() для цикла в котором происходит чтение из соккета и ввод с клавиатуры.

Comment: @mikelsv, а usleep() (Sleep()) - зачем в такой задачке? 

Тут обычно используют select() (poll() или epoll() (последний, наверное, удобней всего, но он только в linux)).

Comment: @avp, нужно проверять еще и сообщения с клавиатуры. Это все под виндой, поэтому select() используется только для соккетов.

Comment: @miklsv, т.е. Вы делали Sleep(), а потом опрашивали сокеты через select() и клавиатуру (и то и другое без ожидания)?

Если так, то почему не использовать таймаут (последний параметр) в select()?

А правильней здесь, наверное, было бы использовать 2 потока (в одном select с сокетами, а в другом чтение с клавиатуры с ожиданием).

Comment: Ну про select() @mikelsv уже писал -- это винды. Где select(), а где клавиатура. А вот два потока -- дело другое. Кстати, в cygwin'е select() по описанию как раз и реализован через дополнительный поток.

Comment: Мне нравятся ваши фантазии. Что еще ненужного прикрутить? ) Излишнее усложнение, ладно бы оно добавляло новые возможности, так нет, оно делает то же самое, но сложнее.
То-то я недолюбливаю cygwin.

Comment: @mikelsv, IMHO select в cygwin-e позволяет также смотреть клавиатуру. Так что программа получится проще, а не сложнее.

--

Самое главное, что в цикле со Sleep() Вам не удастся обработать действительно много соединений (скажем, десять тысяч в секунду (возможно к виндоус это не относится)).

Comment: @mileksv, оказывается sleep тоже имеется в Linux :(
надо что-то похожее...

Comment: @mikelsv эти фантазии называются реализацией POSIX.1 (если склероз мне не изменяет) поверх win32api. Что уж поделаешь, креативность разработчиков винды, однако. А уж как там fork тормозит...

Answer (score 3):

Самая простая и лежащая на поверхности - ввод-вывод (stdin/stdout) **русских букв** в windows и *nix. Программа также должна корректно работать при перенаправлении (`>`,`<`) в файл (из файла).

Поиграйтесь часок-другой и у Вас появится масса конкретных вопросов.

Comment: И близкая проблема локалей и интернационализации

Answer (score 2):

Если понимать под кроссплатформенным программированием - программирование поверх виртуальных машин, то основные проблемы это:

1. Наличие собственно виртуальной машины под той или иной осью
2. Физическое наличие виртуальной машины в конкретной станции (даже если есть порт виртуальной машины для данной оси, не всегда гарантируется ее наличие в конкретном случае). Связанная с этим проблема - проблема гладкой установки виртуальной машины. Обычно требуются административные права на установку виртуальной машины, так что вопрос переносимости утыкается в вопрос прав юзера.
3. Проблема версионности виртуальной машины. Если прога написана под одну версию виртуальной машины, она запросто может не работать под более ранней версией
4. Проблема скорости работы - при прочих равных условиях обычно кроссплатформенное приложение более медленно чем нативное приложение. Конечно, есть способы ее решения, как то JIT компиляторы и проч., но это все равно не снимает проблему.
5. Проблема стыковки кроссплатформенного приложения с нативными частями. Иногда в целях повышения скорости работы некоторые критические по скорости участки программы пишутся в нативных кодах, при портировании сразу же возникает проблема переноса этих участков.

Ну как то так.

Comment: Но как мне исследовать ту или иную проблему? Допустим если взять проблему версий ВМ и Python и попробовать запустить одну и ту же программу под разными версиями ВМ, ошибок вроде не будет. Нужно использовать что-то другое? Просто проблему мне кажется надо выбрать более глобальнее.

Comment: Если прога будет использовать фичи ВМ более свежей версии, то под старой ВМ она не пойдет или если все хорошо заточено, то потребует установить новую версию ВМ. Попробуйте так.

Comment: Да, но это нельзя назвать проблемой. Она слишком легко решается, и не думаю что в моей работе это примут. Может есть какие-нибудь проблемы с использованием какой-либо библиотеки или без? Тоесть, протестировать с библиотекой и без на ОСях Linux и Windows.

Comment: "Если понимать под кроссплатформенным программированием - программирование поверх виртуальных машин..."

Java -- не кроссплатформенный инструмент. Это -- отдельная платформа ((c) не помню чей)

Comment: Виртуальная машина -- совсем необязательно

Answer (score 2):

Проблемой, например, является то, что хотя языки и определяют размеры переменных различных типов и диапазоны значений, которые они могут принимать, но на разных платформах эти типы могут себя по-разному вести. Например, сишный тип int при компиляции под ДОС имеет разрядность 16 бит, при компиляции под win32 - 32 бита, а при сборке под linux x64 - 64 бита.

Потом проблемы могут вызывать разное поведение стандартных функций. Не говоря уже о том, если потребуется работа со сторонними библиотеками. Запросто может оказаться, что на какой-то определенной платформе нет какой-то жизненно необходимой для работы ПО функции...

Как заметил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), очень часто вызывает проблемы локализация программ, причем такая, чтоб программа работала везде. Это связано с тем, что в разных системах свои подходы к решению данного вопроса. Есть, конесно, стандартные языковые средства в с++ для локализации, но назвать их достаточными нельзя...

Comment: Дос как бы уже все. А у меня под линуксом int 32 бита. Не путайте с long, он да, становится 64 битным. Я стараюсь сам рулить разрядностью, чтобы как раз не возникало разных неожиданных проблем. Пока не додумаются переделать разрядность char, short, int и double я спокоен. )

Функции да. Не дадите парочку примеров стандартных функций работающих по разному? Сторонние библиотеки отдельная песня, особенно если они есть только под одну систему или совершенно не переносятся.

Comment: >Не дадите парочку примеров стандартных функций работающих по разному?

readdir() :-)

Comment: Хм, readdir() есть только под линуксом и я не припоминаю, чтобы оно работало как-то не так. у FindFirstFile() другая реализация, но работает в принципе так же.

Comment: @klopp а уж работа с windows registry под unix-like'ами -- вообще не в дугу. (Кстати, можно вспомнить и недавнее обсуждение peekb)

Comment: Понятия не имею, зачем ты сюда приплетаешь пикопоки и реестр. Вообще-то я о том, что и не всякий стандарт везде реализован, и даже элементарные (одинаковые!) задачи везде приходится решать по-разному. Вот и пример "кроссплатформенности" :-)

Comment: @klopp Пожалуй правда. readdir достаточно универсальная функция. Хотя файловые системы бывают сильно разными.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще проблему кроссплатформенного GUI вспомнить.

Answer (score -2):

Использование не стандартных библиотек ведет к проблеме кроссплатформенного программирования. Проблема устраняется установкой нужных библиотек, если они есть для этой платформы.

Comment: @perfect, как раз установка недостающих библиотек - это **не решение**. 

Пример решния на уровне сборки из исходников можно увидеть, когда Вы запускаете configure и скрипт в зависимости от **наличия уже установленных** библиотек формирует правильный makefile.

Похожий подход возможен и при запуске исполнимого модуля. Он динамически подгружает нужные разделяемые библиотеки (переключаясь на более эффективный алгоритм, если необходимая библиотека установлена). Естественно обращение к функциям в этом случае косвенное с передварительной выборкой адреса по имени функции.

Comment: Не все платформы бинарно совместимы. Вполне возможно, что будет нужна перекомпиляция программы, если не изменение исходного кода под конкретную платформу.

Comment: Странно, а я всегда смотрел есть ли нужная библиотека например под nix и win платформу и уже исходя из этого принимал решение использовать ее или нет.

ps
Например библиотека opengl

Comment: @perfect, это (смотреть есть ли библиотеки для прплатформы), конечно, тоже правильный подход к проектированию программы. Нет знакомой библиотеки в XYZ  - не делаем программу для системы XYZ.